# Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

Suppose I used TcpListener to start listen any IP address and port, it works for the first time. But soon after I restart the program, I got this error 'Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted'. It sounds like I didn't close tcpListener when I exit my program, I did that in Form_closing but didn't works. Later I found a way to solve this problem by changing my port each time, although this could fix problem I need a fix port. Here how my codes look like.

```
TcpListener tcpListener;
Socket socketClient;
const int PORT_LISTEN_SERVER = 7568;

tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT_LISTEN_SERVER);
tcpListener.Start();                        //Error at this line
socketClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
IPEndPoint ipend = (IPEndPoint)socketClient.RemoteEndPoint;
toolStripLabel1.Text = "Connection from " + IPAddress.Parse(ipend.Address.ToString());
```

How I close my listener connection

```
try
{
 MessageBox.Show("Try to clean up!");
 tcpListener.Stop();
 socketClient.Close();
}
catch { MessageBox.Show("Error CleanUp!"); }
```

---

**Updated:**
Suppose I changed into function make recursion. To check perhaps tcpListener's stop method could solve this problem. Every time I try to run the function, I'm keep getting Error Message. It seems like stop method could not solve this.

```
private void BeginListen()
{           
 try
 {
  tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT_LISTEN_SERVER);
  tcpListener.Start();
  MessageBox.Show("tcpListener is started");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { 
  MessageBox.Show("Error at: " + ex);
  tcpListener.Stop();
  BeginListen();
}
```

[image: Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted]

Comment: are you sure your listener is being closed? Form.Closing does not always fire, it depends on how you close your application.

Comment: Did you try to close socketClient before closing listener? Did you use a `try..catch` to see if you got an error while trying to close socket/listener?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I'm sure my codes get executed

Comment: if you had two messages show up then you seem to have found your problem -- you are getting an exception trying to clean up. What exception are you getting?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Well,I just solved it myself. Socket.Close is executed before it assign to.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I just solved it myself. Socket.Close is executed before it assign to. – user3138965